# Unable to login to Application using CAS and Spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security, cas

1.
I have setup a CAS server up and running at port: 8443 url -> `https://ekansh/cas.`
I can see the login page and i am successfully able to login using mysql database user table credentials. and even logout and see status.

2. I created a demo grails app, installed spring security plugin and created user role mappings by s2-quickstart. and scaffolding domains.
3. I added the

   ```
   compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
   compile ":spring-security-cas:2.0-RC1"
   ```

   dependencies.
4. Added configurations in Config.grovy

   `grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.active = true
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = '/login'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.sendRenew = false
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = 'http://ekansh:8095/app1/j_spring_cas_security_check'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlEncoding = 'UTF-8'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.key = 'grails-spring-security-cas'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.artifactParameter = 'ticket'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceParameter = 'service'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.filterProcessesUrl = '/j_spring_cas_security_check'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.proxyCallbackUrl = 'http://ekansh:8095/app1/secure/receptor'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.useSingleSignout = true
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix = 'https://ekansh:8443/cas'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.proxyCallbackUrl = 'http://ekansh:8095/app1/secure/receptor'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.proxyReceptorUrl = '/secure/receptor'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl ='https://ekansh:8443/cas/logout?url=http://ekansh:8095/app1/'
   grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['casAuthenticationProvider']`

Nw when i run this app, i get redirected to cas server page, i enter the credentials, it logs me into cas server, but it sends me to the spring security login page with message that

`Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password.` And i am not even able to sign in to the application from this point.

What am i missing ? Why am i getting spring security login page.

I also found that when i comment line `grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['casAuthenticationProvider']`, i am able to login to the system. I have not altered the `casAuthenticationProvider`.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question after a lot of research. Basically i did mess up with the configurations of the cas server.

The user was getting logged into the cas server but a ticket was not being generated for the same user, thus it was still sending a user not authenticated response back to the application and spring security, was redirecting to the login page.

Comment: I am having the same problem can you share your cas server configuration sample ?